# Get-ADUser for multiple users across different servers

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Ok, so I have a bit of a conundrum. I have a list of users I'm trying to get information for, via AD and I've got a nice little script I've found to get those users (shown below). The only hiccup I have is there are two potential servers where the users could be coming from and I'm only seeing from the one server.

```
Get-Content \\C:\Users.txt |
foreach-object{
Get-ADUser -filter {SamAccountName -eq $_} -Properties "Name,EmailAddress" |
Select-Object SamAccountName,Name,EmailAddress} |
Export-CSV 'C:\Email Addresses.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

The issue is that I'm not sure which server the users might be in. For the sake of simplicity, the servers can be labeled "Server1.com" and "Server2.com"

Would I need to do some kind of nested foreach? Is it also possible to list the server in the CSV, so it shows SamAccountName,Server,Name,EmailAddress? Would an If statement work? What would be the easiest thing to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: How many users are there on each server? How many users are in the text file? `Get-ADUser` has a `-Server` parameter if you need to target a server. You could query for every user against the server that has the least amount of latency. For each user that is found, you can remove that user from the list. So that when you move on to the next server, the query list is shorter. Another option is to query all users from all servers. Then just search within those results for your users. There are tradeoffs to either approach.

Comment: You could also have one `Get-AdUser` command per server. If a user is found before the last command, you could skip remaining commands to save time/resources

Comment: I anticipate only about 25 users will be in the text file at any one time. I'm not too worried about latency.

Comment: Additionally, most of the users will be on the main server. Would it make more sense to just have an if for the few that return null values and then search for them on the alternate server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested foreach is the way I usually go as I have yet to find a better way to query all of AD for this information.

If you know the servernames you can place them in an array and loop through them for each user object.  If a user object is returned you can break out of the server loop and move on to the next user.  I usually start with the quickest server that contains the majority of my users and then order the rest accordingly.

Code is something like this

```
$servers = @("Server1", "Server2", "Server3")

Get-Content "C:\Users.txt" |
ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($server in $servers) {
        $aduser = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$_'" -Properties Name, Mail -Server $server | Select-Object SamAccountName, Name, Mail
        if ($aduser) {
            $aduser # send object down the pipeline
            break   # break out of server loop and move to next user
        }

    }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\temp\testemail.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: That's great! My only question would be, is there a way to list what server the result is coming from? I couldn't seem to find one from the get-aduser properties technet.

Comment: You can create a new property on your result from Select-Object that captures the server from the loop.  `Select-Object SamAccountName, Name, Mail, @{name = 'Server'; expression = { $server } }`